# Custom style xml file for editText

Tags: android, android-xml, android-styles

I am making android application with list-view & form-view,So i need a help with **custom style file** for my form-view of application.So, can any one suggest me **how to make** custom style files or **examples of custom style files** for my form-view.In my form-view i have **Buttons,Edit-Text,& Text-View** .Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

create style you want to apply in your component like Button,EditText,TextView in style file

```
    <style name="buttons_style" >
      <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
      <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item> 
      <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/Text_size28</item>
      <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
      <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">#404042</item>
      <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
      <item name="android:drawablePadding">5dp</item>
      <item name="android:drawableRight">@drawable/arrow_right</item>
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/input_gray_selector</item>

</style>
```

and apply this to your components like below

```
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/mybutton"
        style="@style/buttons_style"/>
```

Comment: thank you.Now i understand how to create custom style files & apply it to components